# Bluescreen on windows 10 after using android emulator

Tags: windows, android-emulator, blue-screen-of-death

today after i got an update of avast i could not launch any android emulator anymore (Bluestacks 3 and NOX). When i try to launch an emulator after like 80-90% of the engine loading of the emulator nothing happens then i get a messagge of the emulator that the engine could not launche and it gives me 2 options (restart engine or restart computer) both will get my sistem to crash and i get a blue screen with errorcode 0x00000667 (not sure if i miss a 0). I already tried to disable the antivirus and to retry but got the same problem, i reinstall the android emulator but got the same result. And worst of my problems are that my computer didn't had the file protection active to restore to an prewvie point, so im stuck now and i prefer not to reset my whole computer. Any suggestion what could i do? im really in trouble here and i hope this is the right place to ask for my problem.

Comment: Ok, i solve it alone xD
after avast updated it activates me 2 things Service reputation and CyberCapture (not sure if the names are the same in english, im from italy btw) and after deactivating this 2 options now it runs smothly like it did before.
I hope this can help someone in the future with my same problem.

Comment: I got the same problem today so unchecking the 2 things mentioned didn't solve my problem, i uninstalled avast and now it works so i guess it was avast fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same exact issue. Did all the normal troubleshooting (restarts/re-installs etc). So I hit up google and found your post and made the connection that I recall updating Avast a few days ago as well. Did a search for "avast bluestacks" and found the post @ this URL. I followed its easy steps and so far bluestacks is back up and running normal for me again.

https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003212603-Solution-for-Avast-antivirus-makes-BlueStacks-run-slow-

Comment: Your URL is about Avast slows down BlueStacks, but not about BSOD.

Comment: Irregardless of the title, the steps still resolved the issue of the application crashing. Avast was certainly conflicting with bluestacks. I have since moved off of that anti-virus and use bitdefender and I have no issue with blue stacks anymore. I live stream in on youtube almost every night.

Answer (score 24):

Turning off hyper-v in your pc will fix the problem. Run the `CMD` in administrative mode and run this command `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`.

Comment: Also, if "Virtual Machine Platform" is off, try turning that on in Control Panel->Turn Windows features on or off.

Comment: Should we enable it again after we're done with the emulator?

Comment: This fixed my problem

Comment: It's the problem. take me 5 hours of efforts

Comment: After running this command, restarting and attempting to launch an emulator via Android Studio, I get an error in Android Studio that HAXM is not installed. :(

Answer (score 14):

Solve this

1 - Enable virtualization (from bios/UEFI setting)

2 - Disable hyper-v and restart (Credit to Sadhurshan)
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

3 - Install intel haxm
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

Comment: Virtualization is Hyper-V virtualization isn't it? What differences between your virtualization (Step1) and hyper-v virtualization?

Comment: I guess Saiful meant the bios/UEFI setting for virtualization in step one

Comment: I had to do steps 1. and 2. (don't forget to restart PC), then upgrade HAXM and download another/fresh Android System Image.

Answer (score 2):

Run the CMD in administrative mode and run this command bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Run the CMD in administrative mode and run command
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`.

But just this step didn't work.

As a second step, I checked whether *Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)* is installed on the SDK Manager > SDK Tools. I saw the "update available" and updated it.

Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

disable hyper-v  and restart then open nox try again in windows 10 disable
Press Windows key.
Type "Turn Windows features on or off"
Deselect checkbox next to Hyper-V.
Select OK.
Select Restart now.

Answer (score 0):

Never expected that this would work, but it worked for my good old fasion i7-2600k which does not support VT but has Hardware acceleration.

1. Make sure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features
2. Uninstall NoxPlayer (probably similar to  Bluestacks)
3. Disable Hardware Acceleration in your BIOS
4. Install NoxPlayer, do a first run with an emulator.
5. Restart and enable Hardware Acceleration in your BIOS again to improve performance.

source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VedP_MamreA

Answer (score 0):

The problem can easily be solve by using following steps:

- Turn off battery saver mode if it ON.
- Close the bluestack application.
- Open task manager or Press Ctrl+shift+Esc and end all Background process with bluestack.
  (The 3-4 process are

  - Bluestack 4
  - Bluestack Agent
  - Bluestack Android host
  - Bluestack Server Interface
    ).
- Close all applications.
- Restart the bluestack application.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue on my new spec: R5 5600X on MSI B550M.

This is how i solved it:

1. Uninstall windows updates: **Didn't Work.**
2. Enable SVM(Must be enabled anyway): **Didn't Work.**
3. Refresh Windows(Download from Cloud): **Worked :)**